# Jmeter Multiple Users Summary report analysis

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I ran performance test for multiple concurrent threads. The average response time for 1 thread is **36** and for 5 threads is **88**. How do I interpret this? Should I divide the value 88 by 5, so that I get the response time for 1 thread? What does **88** mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Glossary](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420385-Glossary)

> **Average(Aggregate Report)**
>
> This is the average response time for each label in the script. While the test is running it will display the average of the requests already executed and the final value once test execution is finished.

Average == [Arithmetic_mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) for all the requests which have the same name. Arithmetic mean is basically the sum of all response times divided by their count.

I would recommend considering looking into other metrics, like 90/99 Percentile and into charts from i.e. [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) as "average" approach can mask a spike in the response time and you will be uninformed of a possible performance problem

Comment: Hi, I understand the meaning of average response time. But my doubt is, when I run only 1 thread, average is 36ms.However, when I run 5 threads at a time, average becomes 88ms. So, It's higher than 1 thread. Should I divide 88ms by 5 or how can I infer this?